# Placing buttons in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position these 8 buttons in the right position (so left button in the left side of the rectangle, right button on the right side and so on). Do i need to have a div for each button and then position it inside "camButton" or can it be done without this many divs?

```css
.button {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 4px;
}

.button__arrow {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.button__arrow--up {
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(127, 0, 255);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(127, 0, 255);
  transform: translateY(25%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="camButtonsParent">
  <div id="camButtons">
    <button class="button">
        <div class="button__arrow button__arrow--up"></div>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `grid` and instead of making arrows using `css` use `svg` because it is very confusing to code with and will be difficult to maintain. Not to mention but your code and naming is quite confusing and headache.

Comment: Which eight buttons?

Comment: It was edited by a moderator, you can see it on the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem and help you align your buttons like you wanted.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.container button {
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.container button:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container button:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Top Left</button>
  <button>Top</button>
  <button>Top Right</button>
  <button>Left</button>
  <button>Center</button>
  <button>Right</button>
  <button>Bottom Left</button>
  <button>Bottom</button>
  <button>Bottom Right</button>
</div>
```

**Created same with `SVG` icons.** like I mentioned in the comments.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.container button {
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.container button i {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.container button:nth-child(1) i,
.container button:nth-child(9) i {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.container button:nth-child(3) i,
.container button:nth-child(7) i {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container button:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container button:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<div class="container">
  <button>
        <i class='bx bx-chevron-up'></i>
    </button>
  <button>
        <i class='bx bx-chevron-up'></i>
    </button>
  <button>
        <i class='bx bx-chevron-up'></i>
    </button>
  <button>
        <i class='bx bx-chevron-left'></i>
    </button>
  <button>
        <i class='bx bxs-circle'></i>
    </button>
  <button>
        <i class='bx bx-chevron-right'></i>
    </button>
  <button>
        <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i>
    </button>
  <button>
        <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i>
    </button>
  <button>
        <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards grid and svgs. The code is cleaner indeed this way.